# UWP: ConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync doesn't work

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to get the incoming and outgoing traffic from a WAN Miniport (IKEv2) interface but it doesn't work.
First I'm creating a new VPN profile and then I'm connecting the profile. This works fine. After that I would like to get the incoming and outgoing traffic but I get every time 0. Here is my code

```
var internetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (internetConnectionProfile.ProfileName != profileName) // I'm checking to see if this is my VPN profile
{
    return;
}

var usageStates = new NetworkUsageStates
{
    Roaming = TriStates.DoNotCare,
    Shared = TriStates.DoNotCare
};


var networkUsage = await internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkUsageAsync(
    this.startTime, //Saved when the profile is connected
    DateTimeOffset.Now, 
    DataUsageGranularity.Total, 
    usageStates);

ulong completeTrafic = 0;
foreach(var usage in networkUsage)
{
    completeTrafic = usage.BytesReceived + usage.BytesSent; //Everytime it's 0
}
```

One interesting point is that `usage.ConnectionDuration` it's not 0, it's somehow correct. I think is 10 seconds less than what I see in Network and Sharing Center -> Right click on the interface -> Status. In the Status dialog it's showing correctly the Sent and Receive bytes.

My project settings:

[image]

My Windows version is Windows 10 1703.

Answer (score 0):

By testing on my side, the above code snippet can work well and both the sent and receive bytes are not 0. So that there's nothing wrong with the code itself.

[image]

Please try to check if any parameters are incorrect. For example, the `profileName` is the correct one you want to test, the `startTime` is setting correctly to be able to get the usage. Otherwise there may be somethings wrong with the connection profile. Please try to check the internet connection, or try another connection profile for testing.

More details please reference the  [official sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Network-Information-Sample-63aaa201).

Comment: I tried with the local area network profile and it works fine. For some reason I can't get the Network usage for my VPN profile. I checked all parameters and profileName and everything seems fine. I will check my code on Windows version 1709 to see if it works there.

Comment: Without using UWP app, can the VPN  connection itself work find ? Can you access anything with the VPN connection?

Comment: After discussing with one of your Microsoft colleague from professional technical support we realized that the root cause is an underlying exception being thrown causing GetNetworkUsageAsync to bail out too early. Unfortunately until the issue is fixed this function does not work for WAN Miniport (IKEv2) interfaces.